# how to angular JS get complex json

Tags: angularjs, json, nested

i need to take child array in this json . i tried too many ways, how can i take kindC -> name . Plz help !!
Full map:

```
   [
 {
 "direction": {
       "book": "A",
       "note": "B"
 },
 "prize": {
       "kindA": [],
       "kindB": [],
       "kindC": [{
          "name": "Target#1",
          "_id": "32131"
       }]
    },
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Just access the prize object

```
console.log(data[0].prize.kindC);
```

if you need to access the 1st object

console.log(data[0].prize.kindC[0].name);

**DEMO**

```js
var data = [
  {
    "direction": {
      "book": "A",
      "note": "B"
    },
    "prize": {
      "kindA": [],
      "kindB": [],
      "kindC": [
        {
          "name": "Target#1",
          "_id": "32131"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
console.log(data[0].prize.kindC[0].name);
```

Comment: yes. prize element of user array . so access like that not worked

Comment: post your whole json

Comment: is it something like this? http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=fae0787d293e374f9c9855b839b90b39

Comment: check the demo attached

Comment: how can i take kindC -> name

Comment: Thank you., it worked . so need data[0] in parrent array .

Comment: no you have not, you need to click the tick mark next to answer

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = [
  {
    "direction": {
      "book": "A",
      "note": "B"
    },
    "prize": {
      "kindA": [],
      "kindB": [],
      "kindC": [
        {
          "name": "Target#1",
          "_id": "32131"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

console.log(jsonObj[0].prize.kindC[0].name);
```